# C# - Display Multi-line TextBox count in real-time

Tags: c#, list, counter, multiline

I have a multi-line TextBox that I can either type or paste items into.At the bottom of the textbox I have an "Item Count = " label and "0" textbox next to it.

I would like the text in the "0" textbox to keep track of the number of items in my textbox list in real time.  Is this possible?

This is what I have, but I can't get it to work:

```
 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char[] delimiterChars = { ',', ':', '|', '\n' };
        List<string> sortBox = 
              new List<string>(textBox_ListSource.Text.Split(delimiterChars));
        var itemCount = sortBox.Count();
        textBox_SourceCount.Text = itemCount;
    }
```

I am getting a red squiggly under the "itemCount" in the last line. It won't compile and says can't explicitly convert 'int' to 'string'.

Comment: Can you describe what is it wrong that your code does?

Comment: I am getting a red squiggly under the "itemCount" in the last line.  It won't compile and says can't explicitly convert 'int' to 'string'.

Comment: ah! I edited your post and barely noticed that syntax error!! @Jeagr remember to explain what the problem is always, when asking a question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
textBox_SourceCount.Text = itemCount.ToString();
```

Also, you don't need to use the LINQ Count function as a List has a Count property.

```
var itemCount = sortBox.Count(); // Calls a LINQ function which calls the Count property
var itemCount = sortBox.Count; // Calls the Count property directly
```

For future reference, C# will not automatically cast an `int` to a `string`. You need to perform the conversion explicitly in most cases.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - LINQ is optimized to use the `Count` property when you call `Count()` on lists anyway. The overhead is so minimal that it doesn't really matter for any practical purpose.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I actually deleted a comment just a couple minutes ago saying the same thing. It's more a matter of best practice then productivity and I only mentioned it because the OP seems to be pretty new to C#. Just wanted to make him/er aware that they were calling a function.